# .NET reference (Method not found)

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I am receiving an error at this line

```
return folder.SubFolders.Aggregate(count, (current, subfolder) =>
               GetFilesCount(subfolder, current));
```

Error is

> Error 1   'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolderCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Aggregate' and no extension method 'Aggregate' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFolderCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Rest of code is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;

 namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
 {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (SPSite currentSite = new SPSite(txtSiteAddress.Text))
                {
                    SPWeb currentweb = currentSite.OpenWeb();
                    var webtree = new TreeViewItem();
                    webtree.Header = currentweb.Title;
                    webtree.Tag = currentweb;
                    MapFolders(currentweb.Folders, webtree);    
                }
             }
             catch (Exception a)
             {
                MessageBox.Show(a.ToString());
             }
        }

        private void MapFolders(SPFolderCollection folderList,
                                             TreeViewItem treeNode)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < folderList.Count; i++)
            {
                var item = new TreeViewItem();
                item.Header = string.Format("{0} ({1})", folderList[i].Name,
                                             GetFilesCount(folderList[i], 0));
                item.Tag = folderList[i];

                treeNode.Items.Add(item);

                if (folderList[i].SubFolders.Count > 0)
                    MapFolders(folderList[i].SubFolders, item);
            }
        }

        private int GetFilesCount(SPFolder folder, int count)
        {
            count += folder.Files.Count;

            return folder.SubFolders.Aggregate(count, (current, subfolder) =>
                   GetFilesCount(subfolder, current));
        }



    }
}
```

I am trying to make a windows form application, as in link below,

[enter link description here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2011/10/27/sharepoint-api-download-upload-documents-tool.aspx)

I Made Changes to the line to use cast but its says

```
return folder.SubFolders.Cast(count, (current, subfolder) =>
               GetFilesCount(subfolder, current));
```

and new Error is

> Error 1   No overload for method 'Cast' takes '2' arguments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ only works on generic collections.
`SPFolderCollection` implements `IEnumerable`, but not `IEnumerable<SPFolder>`.

You need to call `.Cast<SPFolder>()`.

Comment: can you explain it a little bit please

Comment: I already read that before posting my question here , but am finding it bit hard to understand :/ , as i dont even understand what this line of code is doing :( ..

Comment: except its returning folder.subfolder () if number is equal to or greater then getfilescount....

Comment: `.Cast<T>()` creates an `IEnumerable<T>` that wraps an untyped `IEnumerable`.  This allows you to use LINQ extension methods.

Comment: can you explain me with example please ?

Comment: @user1090104, the link SLaks provided has an example. Unless by "example" you mean "write my code for me". SLaks is not going to be around every time you need to write code; you will have to learn how to do so yourself.

Comment: @Dour High Arch , I did made an effort, if you look at the code I developed from that blog, you will realize the changes, but now I am stuck somewhere and my mind is like stuck sumwhere... and defiantly I will gonna learn if you will tell me... as am not sitting in an exam room am I ?

Comment: I looked at the apple and mango example but that's where they are using arrays but what i am doing is , using folders and sub folders , which i am feeling hard to understand , if that make sense ? :)

Comment: @DourHighArch its good to learn and do it yourself but he clearly stated he attempted and was having a hard time understanding. We all started somewhere, at least he made the effort to research before coming to ask, give them some credit.